# Make player go through walls (one way wall )

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a feature in my game were it requires the player to go through walls to slove the puzzle i want the player to only go through the wall that has the tag Puzzle Wall ONLY once  then it will no longer work (become a normal wall) after the time end

How can i make it work (you can write a new code since mine has 2 errors  )
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Walls : MonoBehaviour
{

    // This script is for every wall in the game there is 5 types of walls 

    private BoxCollider boxCollider;

    void Start()
    {
        Puzzle.OnPuzzleSolved += ActivateWall("Puzzle Wall"); // why do i get this error                                
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    }

  
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        boxCollider.isTrigger = false;

    }


    private void ActivateWall(string wallTypeToActivate)
    {
        if (wallTypeToActivate == "Puzzle Wall")
        {
            boxCollider.isTrigger = true;

        }
        else if (wallTypeToActivate 
   == " Fake Wall")
        {
            boxCollider.isTrigger = true;

        }
        else if (wallTypeToActivate 
     == "Puzzle Door")
        {
            boxCollider.isTrigger = true;

        }
        else
        {
            boxCollider.isTrigger

   = false;
      }
     }
    }
```

Error 1 i cant pass anything into my action
Error 2 null refrence execption
Error 3 player can go through all walls

I tried to use the on trigger enter / exist but it give me error

I tried using the collison matrix same issue it works but player still can go through it

Comment: Can you provide the code for the wall or the puzzle since we can't know what  is the  "Puzzle" in your case

Comment: We can certainly help with errors, so long as you add them to the question. Give code, get answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored your code and fixed the errors
add a tag with the same name (case sensitive)

in the inspector make sure the timer value is > 0

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;


public class Walls : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float time;
    

    // This script is for every wall in the game there is 5 types of walls 

    private BoxCollider boxCollider;

    void Start()
    {
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();

        Puzzle.OnPuzzleSolved += ActivateWall;                         
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        Puzzle.OnPuzzleSolved -= ActivateWall;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        switch (gameObject.tag)
        { 
            //  if the tag matches We disable the collider on exit so 
            the player can't go back 
            case "Puzzle Wall":
                boxCollider.isTrigger = false;
                gameObject.GetComponent<Walls>().enabled = false;
                break;
            case "Fake Wall":

                boxCollider.isTrigger = true;
                    break;
            case "Puzzle Door":
                boxCollider.isTrigger = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void ActivateWall()
    {
       
       boxCollider.isTrigger = true;
        StartCoroutine(StartTimer());
    }

    IEnumerator StartTimer()
    {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
        boxCollider.isTrigger = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code worked but can you explain how the code works

Comment: When the  OnPuzzleSolved  action is invoked we call the  ActivateWall method which makes the box collider of the wall a trigger 

then when we exit the trigger it checks its tag if it equals to one of the cases  
it executes the code inside that case in your case the puzzle wall becomes penetrable only once when the action is invoked  also we disable the script in that wall so we don't activate it again in some other part of our game